# git android studio ignored file

Tags: android, android-studio

I have cloned a git project in my computer and I want to open it in android studio.

The problem, I don't know how to load the ignored file like gradle etc.

How can I load the git project with my gradle and other ignored files ?

Comment: steps :  git clone,  gradle CLI tasks ( will list tasks ,  gradle "build/test" from the list,  . The CLI build/test tasks will pull in dependencies needed by AS.  THEN, you can import to the IDE